# Are users notified (automatically, manually) on deleted "offensive/rude" comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

As a user who believes he is not a rude person, I find myself wondering if any of my comments have been flagged as rude and removed; mostly for the sake of wondering what I said was rude, and what could possibly be done to fix it in the future.

I can see the pros/cons here, so I was wondering what the opinion of being notified for a rude/offensive comment flag would be.

- Pros: learning from your mistakes
- Cons: potentially leading to off
  topic "call outs" or more comments and inciting discussions not
  needed.

Do we have the restraint to simply accept something we said was determined as rude enough to know when it happens, or is this a case of "ignorance is bliss" (probably a bastardization of that phrase but whatever)?

Comment: No, they are not. Users are only notified if they are to be suspended, but even then I believe it's rare the mod message includes reference to specific comments.

Comment: You aren't notified by the system, no. If, however, a moderator feels that you need to be informed, you will be.

Comment: So basically we have no way to know which comment earned a suspension? That would drive me nuts, seeing as I am not actively being rude (in my opinion)

Comment: well, no, if you receive a suspension for it, you're likely to have been contacted in one way or another. you can then request more info.

Comment: I believe it would be very rare that a user that is given a suspension has no inkling about the reason for the suspension.

Comment: I think a suspension from rude/abusive comments would be handed out manually by a diamond moderator - and you'd most likely be sent an inbox message about it.

Comment: @yivi that somewhat answers it. The second part is more what I'm after here (are we able to handle being told our comments were flagged as offensive/rude)

Comment: I don't believe the second part is an answerable question. Some users could handle it. Some others couldn't.

Comment: Perhaps your right, I'm genuinely not sure I could resist commenting when I truly believed my comment caused no harm.

Comment: There's no real need to resist commenting. you're not gonna go straight to a year long, or even 30 day suspension if you're genuinely not trying to be abusive without getting some kind of warning.

Comment: I can understand wanting to know this, but regarding "Do we have the restraint..." I think if this notification was implemented meta would instantly be filled with "How could anyone think this was rude?!?" posts based on deleted comments that weren't really that important to begin with. Certainly not everyone would react that way, but some people already complain about their comments getting deleted even without a notification.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's why I listed that on my cons list. And I definitely agree. I would like to see it, but I know for sure there would be meta-plenty. But I also like drama so.. win win? :D

Comment: Maybe, but drama could be seen as a form of fun in that case, and don't forget how we feel about fun ;-)